# Chrome and Firefox extension development

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I create extensions for both Chrome and Firefox browsers. For example, for storage access every browser has it's own API.
Chrome: chrome.storage - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage
Firefox: browser.storage - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/get

But Firefox also has *chrome.storage* API. I want to keep things simple and use the same API for both browsers. Is it safe to use *chrome.storage* in Firefox or should I use *chrome.storage* in Chrome and *browser.storage* in Firefox?

Comment: Yes, it is safe.

Comment: Thanks! Any confirmation from mozilla docs that it's safe and won't be deprecated in forseable future?

Comment: They are not legally bound to keep it that way so of course they *can* drop it even though there is no indication available now. Thinking pragmatically, this can happen in two cases: 1) Chrome finally implements Promises-based `browser` API, 2) Firefox becomes the dominant browser.

Comment: Regardless, for a new extension it seems easier to always use `browser` in both browsers via Mozilla WebExtension polyfill.